# How to load C# .dll in Matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I try to load C# .dll in Matlab

```
try
  asm = NET.addAssembly('C:\Temp\SalusCore.dll');
catch e
  e.message;
  if(isa(e, 'NET.NetException'))
    eObj = e.ExceptionObject;
  end
end
```

but i get the below error message:

```
Message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Source: mscorlib
```

Can you tell where i am wrong? I am sure the 'SalusCore.dll' is in 'C:\Temp\' folder and it is compiled successfully in C# compiler.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be loading the header file?

Comment: Sorry, can i ask what means 'loading header file'? The header file is in C# or anywhere else? Thanks!

Comment: The 'SalusCore' is a very big dll and i am not quite sure what's inside. Probably the Matlab cannot recognize some of the data type inside? Thanks!